# Does Ember 2.0 automatically connect handlebar template files to controllers?

Tags: ember.js

I'm creating a very basic Ember application using ember-cli and Ember 2.0. I used ember-cli to generate a template called 'footer.hbs' and the same component named 'footer.js'. Should Ember be able to correctly pick up any expressions I use in the footer.hbs? For example, I'm using the following three files: footer.js, footer.hbs, and application.hbs which imports the partial 'footer'. Why does the {{firstName}} property not show at all?

footer.js - /app/controllers/footer.js
    import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  firstName: "TEST" 
});
```

footer.hbs - /app/template/footer.hbs

```
<footer class='nav navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom'>
  <div class='container'>
      <ul class="footer-social list-inline">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li>{{firstName}}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

application.hbs

```
{{partial 'navigation'}}
{{outlet}}
{{partial 'footer'}}
```

Comment: You should read about [naming conventions](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#naming-conventions) in ember-cli.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your files weren't generated as a component.  I believe what you want to run is:

```
ember g component footer
```

in which case you would just have to put the following in application.hbs:

```
{{navigation}}
{{outlet}}
{{footer}}
```

Edit: looks like you can't call a component 'footer', so would have to call it something like 'footer-nav'

Comment: just as a side note, components should have a dash in them.  `foo-bar`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access your controllers properties in the same template. You have two problems:

```
{{partial 'footer'}}
```

Partial inserts a template, what you want to do is use `render`:

```
{{render 'footer'}}
```

Beyond that /app/template/footer.hbs should be /app/template**s**/footer.hbs

Example on accessing the controller property: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vipiwe/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: `render` still works in 2.0, but it's on its way out: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_notable-breaking-changes-in-ember-2-0

Comment: @Kingpin2k Right because controllers still work in ember 2.0. They'll go at the same time.